# Does an intelligent item used as a stronghold core retain its personality?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, intelligent-magic-items

In a previous question, [How can I have a sentient dungeon (or race thereof) in my story?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110493/how-can-i-have-a-sentient-dungeon-or-race-thereof-in-my-story), I asked if it was possible to build a sentient dungeon and I learned that it was possible using an intelligent item under the *Stronghold Builder's Guidebook* rules.

I recently started playing an intelligent staff as a character and as my final goal i was thinking of building a stronghold using my savings gained from adventuring and becoming its core/ruler.

Can I use myself as a part of wondrous architecture per the *Stronghold Builder's Guidebook* rules without actually losing my personality or abilities? Or must I lose those?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an intelligent item can become a piece of wondrous architecture without losing its personality or special abilities.

Step 1: Intelligent items, like any magic item, can be upgraded to add new items. In this case, add the 9th level psionic power [true mind switch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/mindSwitchTrue.htm).

Step 2: Build a stronghold containing a piece of wondrous architecture, such as elemental protection wall augmentation. Since wondrous architecture is just a stationary magic item, the entire castle wall can be an intelligent item.*

Step 3: Since intelligent items are creatures, and can use their own spells, the first item can now cast true mind switch on the second item. It explicitly retains its own mind, mental ability scores, spell-like abilities and supernatural abilities.

* There is one complication, which is that it's ambiguous whether a wondrous architecture covering the entire stronghold counts as a single item, or multiple items. Wondrous architecture that occupies one room isn't explicitly stated as scaling to an unlimited number of rooms. Wall augmentations are able to affect any number of stronghold spaces, but it also says that each stronghold space counts as a separate magic item for the specific purpose of dispelling.

Comment: Wondrous architecture is able to cover multiple stronghold spaces, for example, an entire giant hall could be enchanted with the zone of truth effect, or a non-detection effect. Thus an entire stronghold can also be able to be enchanted with such an effect. If the "make item intelligent" cost is paid for each and every stronghold space at the same time, then I think that the entire structure should become a single intelligent construct. However, I take your point and can see the ambiguity you speak of.

Comment: Since there is the option to tie the stronghold mobility to a single architecture or object, that might work.