# What are limitations of casting range for an intelligent stronghold core item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, summoning, intelligent-magic-items

If an intelligent item is acting like a core for a fortress from wondrous architecture per [The Stronghold Builder's Guidebook](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/110561/1204) would it be able to cast any spell it wants within the fortress limits or would it be limited to the room where it was placed in?

Comment: Hi Maiko, just FYI, you should be referencing back to the stronghold builder's guide answer in these questions asking us to expand on them, so as for us to have a framework for the whole "core item" concept in the first place and for answering your more specific questions about it. I've added such references to this question [and your previous one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111476/1204); to avoid having your questions closed as unclear you should aim to make sure you do this yourself too.

Answer (score 2):

An intelligent magic item has the same limits as any normal spellcaster, including that spells generally need line of effect from the caster to the target.

If the intelligent item occupies a single room, it can only cast spells within that room (plus a little more, such as if someone opens the door and the item can see part of the adjacent room). Being wondrous architecture doesn't give you clairvoyance, but even if it did, you couldn't cast most spells without physical line of effect.

If the entire stronghold is somehow one single intelligent item, then you could cast at a target anywhere in the dungeon.

Alternatively, each dungeon room could contain its own magic trap, each of which is a separate intelligent item which works for the core.

Comment: In addition to being able to cast anywhere in the dungeon, should any part of it be on the surface, or exist within a giant cavern (such as a dungeon which is partially exposed to the Underdark)  it would be able to cast up to the normal range from the edge of it's "body".